# Unable to make external HTTP connection from Google App Engine PHP 7.2 environment

Tags: wordpress, http, google-app-engine, php-7.2, google-app-engine-php

I'm trying to use the WordPress Importer plugin to migrate my site to Google's App Engine, PHP 7.2 run time. This fails with the error:

> Remote server did not respond'

How can I troubleshoot this further?

The WordPress Importer plugin is able to download media (images) through http(s) and add those to the local media files. This fails. When enabling the debug-mode on the Importer plugin, the error message becomes `Remote server did not respond`.

When I'm looking into the logs of my server, I don't see any tries to access the files at all, so somehow the instance running on AppEngine is not able to fetch the URL's.

One example URL is https://goingontheroad.nl/data/uploads//2009/09/oude_keuken_2.JPG - which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable curl:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/issue-requests

In most cases, you can use CURLite to avoid charges.
For this:
Put php.ini in root dir (same as app.yaml), if not already
In php.ini add:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = 1
```

deploy app. 
If this now working, try replace on

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

But this need billing enabled

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.